# Was this closed due to bad English?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, english

Just wondering, was this Stack Overflow question, [How can you popup two windows and then do stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575988) closed as subjective because of the questioner's bad English?

Comment: it makes me sad that people's grammar and question asking ability is that poor. Not saying that I'm perfect, but seriously, "Javascript is cool:... and do stuff?" [headshake], big thanks to voyager for cleaning up that question

Comment: It makes you sad to know that most people in world are not born into an English-speaking country? Or that English grammar is, in essence, completely incomprehensible and not based on any consistent rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem was the original phrasing.

Some one deleted the *Java5crip7 is kwel*, and I tried to improve phrasing of the question, as it **is** a valid question.

I'd just like he had just asked *How do you open a pop up window with javascript when you close another window?*

Comment: +1 for correct guess and fixing up...

Comment: Thanks, okay, didn't know this. Next time I'll look at the revision history

Answer (score 3):

I was one of the original closers - and as Voyager neatly put it, "Java5crip7 is kwel" was the main trigger.

Also, it was written completely **incoherently** - and **bad English had nothing to do with it** to answer the specific question in this thread (being ESL I'm hardly the first person to cast stones at others' English :)

Also, I wasn't inclined to dig any further, but did the guy actually ever satisfyingly explain WHY he'd want to do something that so far, to the best of my knowledge, only spam pop-ups did? (that wasn't my reason for closing but it did leave a bad impression nonetheless)

Comment: okay, thanks, didn't know about the earlier versions of the question...

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only people who can say for sure are [DVK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119280/dvk), [David Basarab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469/david-basarab), [Chris Ballance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1551/chris-ballance), [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157237/peter), and [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders), but I suppose seeing a question whose title (before edits) started out "JavaScript is cool!" didn't help.

For what it's worth, in light of the edits I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Maybe they thought "JavaScript is cool." was subjective.

Comment: Was "JavaScript is cool" even mentioned? I can't locate it.

Comment: It was part of the question's original title in the edit logs.

Comment: I probably saw the title "Javascript is cool!" and market it as "craptastic"  Give your questions a useful title if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Didn't know about the original title, thanks, glad I asked...

Comment: I think that explains why. "Javascript is Cool!" as the title is definitely not cool in SO!

Answer (score 0):

The English and the phrasing of the question definitely have rooms for improvement, but we are not language expert in English, but in Java or C#, maybe.

Other than that I do not see anything wrong for it to be closed. "subjective and argumentative"? Hmm... I wonder why.

Comment: indeed, that's what I thought.