# Minor: Revision count is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, revisions-list, grace-period

I revised [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579127/) with an updated body and made it CW. It now shows a link that reads "3 revisions" but when you click on it, you see only 2.

I am guessing that moving it to CW is an implicit revision that's hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you made the change within the 5 minute grace period, it won't show up in the revision history.

Comment: That could be what happened (I can't remember if I edited it within the 5-minute window or not!). In any case, if it's not showing in the revision history, I'd argue it shouldn't show up in the count either...

Comment: I agree, but take a look at this question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/five-edits-within-the-first-five-minutes-caused-a-question-to-become-cw If the count wasn't accurate, users wouldn't really have an idea of how far off the auto-wiki is.